# Create a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, html

This is my very first JS code, I followed the instruction of my textbook, but still, the table does not show up on the webpage. I have the `id="eventList"` already added into my HTML and shorten the arrays. here is the code of my JS.

```js
var eventDates = ["July 29, 2018 11:00:00", "July 30, 2018 19:00:00"];

var eventDescriptions = ["Classics Brunch", "Lasers and Light"];

var eventPrices = ["$12", "$12/$18/$24"];

var thisDay = new Date("August 30, 2018");

var tableHTML = "<table id='eventTable'><caption>Upcoming Events</caption> 
                     <tr><th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

var endDate = new Date();
endDate = thisDay.getTime() + 14 * 24 * 61 * 61 * 1000;

for (var i = 0; i < eventDates.length; ++i) {
  var eventDate = new Date();
  eventDate = eventDates[i];

  var eventDay = eventDate.toDateString();

  var eventTime = eventDate.toLocaleTimeString();

  if ((thisDay <= eventDate) && (eventDate <= endDate))
    tableHTML = "<tr><td>eventDay @ eventTime</td><td>description</td> 
      <td>price</td></tr>" + eventDay + eventTime;

    var description = eventDescriptions[i];
    var price = eventPrices[i];

  }

  tableHTML = "</table>";

  document.getElementById("eventList").innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="eventList">
</div>
```

[image: It should look like this]

Comment: `tableHTML = "</table>";` You're completely reassigning `tableHTML` each time. Try concatenating instead, with `+=`, if you want to add to the existing string value.

Comment: check the console for errors `eventDate.toDateString()` is not correct string doesnt have toDateString method

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> tableHTML = "</table>";
> ```

Either time you assign a value to `tableHTML` you overwrite it with a new value and discard the old value.

Perhaps you meant:

```
tableHTML = tableHTML + "</table>";
```

Comment: Well thx for the responses. I did fix the concatenations. But still the code doesn't work! Any other mistakes that I have in the code ?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're constantly re-assigning `tableHTML` when you use `=` - you need to be appending / concatenating the new HTML by using `+=`:

```
var tableHTML = "<table id='eventTable'><caption>Upcoming Events</caption> 
                 <tr><th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Price</th></tr>";

var endDate = new Date();
endDate = thisDay.getTime() + 14 * 24 * 61 * 61 * 1000;

for (var i = 0; i < eventDates.length; ++i) {
var eventDate = new Date();
eventDate = eventDates[i];

var eventDay = eventDate.toDateString();

var eventTime = eventDate.toLocaleTimeString();

if ((thisDay <= eventDate) && (eventDate <= endDate))
    tableHTML += "<tr><td>eventDay @ eventTime</td><td>description</td> 
    <td>price</td></tr>" + eventDay + eventTime;

var description = eventDescriptions[i];
var price = eventPrices[i];

}

tableHTML += "</table>";
```